# Xcode: Segue from embedded ViewController to other ViewController lost Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, segue

i have a ContainerView with Embedded UIViewController. This UIViewController looks in Storyboard the same size as the ContainerView.

My Problem is now, if i create a new segue from the UIViewController to a other UIViewController the size is already the same as the ContainerView. Can i change this, that i see the full Size in Storyboard ?

[CURRENT AS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjzBJ.png)

[EXPECTED AS SCREENSHOT (MONTAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD5Nq.png)

Comment: You need the root view controller to perform the segue, not the contained view controller.

Comment: Mhh, i make the Segue from TableView Click inside the ContainerView. Should this work from the root ViewController ? Have you a example ?

Comment: You could use a delegation pattern back to your root view controller.